# get queryparams (JSON) via url - Angular 5

Tags: json, angular

I'm learning angular & was trying to display only the `userName` from the JSON data which is being sent via URL.
But it's not returning the specific `userName` which I want to display.

**Error is:** TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of null

Example of link: http://10.20.30.40/abc?userInfo=hereIsTheJSON

**JSON:**

```
{ 
      "company":[
         {  
            "A":false,
            "B":4321,
            "C":null,
            "D":"TASTE",
            "E":1,
            "F":null
         },
         {  
            "A":true,
            "B":1234,
            "C":null,
            "D":"TEST",
            "E":0,      
            "F":null
         }
      ],
      "A":false,
      "C":null,
      "E":0,
      "F":null,
      "userName":"Ron Marks",
      "userId":"rMarks"
 }
```

**.TS:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  currentURL: string;
  newArr:any[];
  newObj: any;
  myparams: any;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {

      let userInfo = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('userInfo');
      this.newObj = JSON.parse(userInfo);
      console.log(this.newObj.userName);
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: debug this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('userInfo'): `console.log(userInfo)` is it undefined? or what is `console.log(newObj)`?

Comment: console.log(userInfo) shows the full JSON of type string and console.log(newObj) also shows full JSON but of type object.

Comment: why you don't get it like this queryParams['userInfo'] inside your subscription

Comment: I had did this earlier `this.myparams = queryParams['userInfo'];` and it worked but upon researching ,it was suggested to use otherwise.

Comment: is your queryParams known to angular component ?

Comment: I don't understand your query.Could you please elaborate.